# R ggplot2 plot not displaying correctly (Novice)

Tags: r, ggplot2, exploratory-data-analysis

hey guys first time poster, I'm a total beginner trying to get my head around this for a university project. I've created a dataframe which contains a word count for spam emails and was trying to create a plot to display it all to compare against the legitimate word counts.

The issue is whenever I run I get a plot that looks like this(added ylim(0,10) to make it easier to see but there are supposed to be well over 100,000 occurrences for some words and around 3000 words in total:

I've tried to tweak the code but I'm a bit of a novice in this area so any help would be much appreciated I just want to see the proper count per word. After I intend on combining the plot with one for legitimate emails to draw parallels. Thanks in advance for taking the time to help guys.

I've coded my plot like this:

Comment: Try `ggplot(spamwordcountdf, aes(word, count)) + geom_col(fill = "red")`

Comment: Are you aware of `geom_col`?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys! ggplot is one of my weaker areas. Another stupid question, but is there a way to be able to read all of the words and their counts clearly as it's extremely zoomed out.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `geom_bar` takes the x axis variable, counts the number of occurrences of each, and plots them on the y axis. Since you only have one instance of each word in your `word` column, the y value for each is one. If you want the height of the bars to reflect the value in another column, you need to specify that column as your y variable, and use either `geom_col` or `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` (which are the same thing under the hood).

So in your case, for the data in the picture you posted (see below for reproducible version), the code would be like this:

```r
ggplot(spamwordcountdf, aes(word, count)) +
 geom_col(fill = "red")
```

[image]

---

**Data taken from image in question in reproducible format**

```r
spamwordcountdf <- structure(list(word = c("e", "t", "a", "o", "i", "n", "r", 
"s", "I", "c", "d", "h", "u", "m", "p"), count = c(151062L, 109878L, 
105425L, 103997L, 100761L, 90840L, 89645L, 83720L, 58852L, 54181L, 
47605L, 44695L, 42336L, 38793L, 36867L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("41", 
"55", "7", "139", "15", "276", "174", "24", "73", "141", "46", 
"228", "242", "78", "130"))
```

Comment: I've also noticed that I have so many words that the data is unreadable. Is there a way to counteract this? Thanks

Comment: @Sonichu0161 You need to plot your data in a different way. How many words do you have?

Comment: it's got about 3000 words, would plotting using the top 50 instead be better? I'm more interested in determining differences and similarities between my spam wordcount and a second count with legitimate words.

Comment: I would probably analyse them numerically and display the difference by doing something like a word cloud of top 20 spam and top 20 non-spam, or even a bar plot of the top 10 words with the highest spam:non-spam ratio. Quite an interesting little project - if you're able to share a link to the data I could have a look.